# Can I filter Jira Issues that were created via a mail handler?

Tags: jira

I'm hoping to create a report that will return all of the Issues that were created via a mail handler that we have set up.

I thought about trying to use "reporter=" in the JQL, but that only works in the cases for when the user isn't already in our system (we've set createuser=false).

I'm running 5.2.5, not-OnDemand.

Answer (score 2):

You could work around this by having the mail handler add a unique tag to each issue that it creates, and then just filter on the tag.

Comment: how does one do that? I don't see any option in the mail handler to add a label or a tag to an issue it creates is there something I'm missing in the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA052/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email)?

Comment: There isn't, but if you use the JEMH plugin for mail handling you could do it

Comment: URL for docs on JEMH mail handler's function; Enable Auto Labelling - JIRA Enterprise Message Handler - Plugin People WIki ; ; https://thepluginpeople.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JEMH/Enable+Auto+Labelling

Answer (score 0):

First, create a custom field called *"By Email"*.

than, using [`Script Runner`](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner), add the following script to the workflow, to the `create` transition:

```
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager
cfm = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager()

# read issue description
description = issue.getDescription()
if (description is not None) and ('Created via e-mail received from' in description):
    issue.setCustomFieldValue(cfm.getCustomFieldObjectsByName("By Email"),'By Email')
```

this will add *'By Email'* to all issues created by emails. Than, you can find those issues using the following JQL:

```
"By Email" is not EMPTY
```

Let me know if you're having truble implelenting this solution.

**NOTE:** If the email is sent from an email known to Jira (Jira's user) the sender will be set as the autor of the ticket and his email will not be saved.

Comment: This seems to be only working if the sender email address is unknown to jira. Otherwise it just sets the sender as author to the ticket and does not add any message to the description.

Comment: yes you are right, forgot to mention this, will add this to the answer. tnx!